# Display div depending of selected button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two buttons, so depending of selected button I want to display div:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center" style="padding-bottom:5px">
        <button id="btnMapaMexico" type="button" name="answer" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">CIUDAD DE MÉXICO</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center" style="padding-bottom:5px">
        <button id="btnMapaCuidadCarmen" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">CIUDAD DEL CARMEN</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do to display some div depending of selected button, I think a div something like:

```
<div id="dirDiv"  style="display:none;" onclick="showDiv()">This is my first button</div>
<div id="dirDiv2"  style="display:none;" onclick="showDiv2()">This is my secondbutton</div>
```

And JS for first item something like (it don´t works):

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('dirDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

There is jsFiddle of my first try [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzmnJ/4965/)

Comment: Click events should be registered on `button` instead of `div` right ?

Comment: Yeah, looks like you just have to move your onclick attributes to the corresponding buttons, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

try this answer with css... or [click here for jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzmnJ/4974/)

```
<button id="btnMapaMexico" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" name="answer" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">CIUDAD DE MÉXICO</button>

<div id="dirDiv"  class="hide">Direccion gm
</div>



function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("dirDiv").removeClass('hide');
}
```

css

```
 .hide
    {
      display:none;
    }
```

Comment: I modified jsfiddle to addClass "hide", with the other button clicked but it don´t works, why it occurs? http://jsfiddle.net/vzmnJ/4973/

Answer (score 1):

```
<button id="btnMapaMexico" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" name="answer" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">CIUDAD DE MÉXICO</button>

<div id="MyDiv"  class="hide">Direction
</div>



function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("MyDiv").removeClass('hide');
}

.hide
    {
      display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#btnMapaMexico').click(function(){
    $('#dirDiv').show();
    $('#dirDiv2').hide();
});

$('#btnMapaCuidadCarmen').click(function(){
    $('#dirDiv').hide();
    $('#dirDiv2').show();
});
```

Comment: jQuery was not mentioned as being in use by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the click event on the button with the same function

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center" style="padding-bottom:5px">
            <button id="btnMapaMexico" type="button" name="answer" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="showDiv()">CIUDAD DE MÉXICO</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center" style="padding-bottom:5px">
            <button id="btnMapaCuidadCarmen" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="showDiv1()">CIUDAD DEL CARMEN</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    function showDiv() {
        document.getElementById('dirDiv').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('dirDiv2').style.display = "none";
    }

    function showDiv1() {
document.getElementById('dirDiv').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dirDiv2').style.display = "block";
    }
```

Or Use this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('body').on('click','#btnMapaMexico',function(){
    $('#dirDiv').show();
    $('#dirDiv2').hide();
});

$('body').on('click','#btnMapaCuidadCarmen',function(){
    $('#dirDiv').hide();
    $('#dirDiv2').show();
});

});
```

Comment: jQuery was not mentioned as being in use by the OP.

Comment: Ya it works, but it seen like when page load divs are visible before clic, how can I hidden divs when page loads, and show with click?

Comment: <body onload="myFunction()"> add the code to hide the div in myFunction()